# Do using directives hurt performance or increase app size compared to full namespaces?

Tags: c#, namespaces, using-directives

I read somewhere that when you add `using System;` to your `.cs` file, the compiler (or maybe something else) adds all `System` related classes to your .cs file and so maybe it is better to not always add `using System;` and instead reference your `DateTime` with its full namespace like this: `System.DateTime`, for example, if it is easy enough to do and few things reference `System` it in your .cs file.

Is that true and if so, can that hurt performance or increase the size of the app? If so, I realize that `using System;` is easier to write and is a convenience and so therefore, you must weigh convenience with performance. It also might be the case that only adding a `using System;` might not make much difference but when many references are added, maybe it could? Thanks!

Comment: *I read somewhere that nonsense nonsense nonsensical nonsense.* Where have you read that?

Comment: Hit the guy that wrote this. Adding `using`-statements exists for one reason: make your life easier. Use it to not allways have to write the fully qualified name of every single type. It also makes your code much more readable. Basically it makes no difference if you write `System.DateTime` within the code or use `DateTime` in combvination with a `using` as you need a reference to mscorlib in either case.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Haha I was looking for the source but am not able to find it. It is possible I read something wrong or assumed it from reading related information.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Thank you sir for the answer and explanation! Definitely good to know that I am not hurting performance by keeping my sanity.

Comment: Even *if* it would hurt your performance you shouldn´t care about those nano-seconds. There seem to be bigger issues within your code than those mirco-optimizations (again *if* even existing)

Comment: @HimBromBeere I work with mobile apps so app size and performance are important but it seems many micro-optimizations in C# are not worth our time especially when looking at it from a maintainability perspective?

Comment: @hvaughan3 - you should always prefer to set goals, *measure*, compare to the goals, and *if needed*, analyse (to identify the hog), rather than trying to learn "rules" for performance or size.

Comment: There is a myth that the using directive causes a load of the assembly containing the classes, but this is incorrect. Assemblies are loaded on first use; the presence of the using directive is only syntactic sugar. Use it or not - its only there for readability. In the MVC world where you have many classes etc called the same thing, I personally prefer to explicitly prefix - but again its only a source code/intellisense preference and has no impact on runtime.

Comment: The source was probably a C++ developer.  In C++ when you use a using directive the compiler will import all the functions of the namespace into scope.
From https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/using-declarations-and-using-directives/:  "The using directive `using namespace std;` tells the compiler to import all of the names from the std namespace into the current scope".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both ***using directive*** and ***full namespace*** generate the same IL.

[image]

[image]

It might be very tiny bit of extra work for Language compiler, but you want to sacrifice for readability.

[image]

*Overview of the compile-time and runtime processes diagram is from [Illustrated C# 2012 by Daniel Solis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430242787)*

Comment: `using` *directive*, not `using` *statement*. There are two distinct features in C# that use the keyword `using`. Using the name of *one* when you in fact mean the *other* can only lead to confusion.

Comment: Great answer and thank you! Did not think about checking the differences in the compiler outcome code.

Answer (score -1):

Mention like

`System.Console.WriteLine("Something");`

this easy to Understanding purpose Only. But Developer Point of Each Time don't mention fully Qualify Names.

So That Time using Namespaces `Using.System`

Answer (score -2):

If you use "using System;" you have access to all methods inside the System class.
Your class has a "link" to all of System.
If you write "using System.DateTime;" as example you only have access to the DateTime functions.
In my opinion it is better to use the specified using like "using System.DateTime".
With that you don't have links to "uneccessary" classes/methods in your .cs file.
Also the "using System" does not include all Methods that are inside of the System.
Examples for this are the IO class or the Xml Class.
If you want to use these you have to write "System.IO." before your method call or you have to write using System.IO;